# Grouping consecutive rows where date difference is 1 day

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, date-range

I have managed to get the dataframe with these columns:

```
+----------+----------+--------+
|      date| next_date|datediff|
+----------+----------+--------+
|2020-09-25|2020-09-30|       5|
|2020-09-30|2020-10-01|       1|
|2020-10-01|2020-10-02|       1|
|2020-10-02|2020-10-03|       1|
|2020-10-03|2020-10-04|       1|
|2020-10-09|2020-11-23|      45|
|2020-11-23|2020-11-24|       1|
|2020-11-24|2020-11-25|       1|
|2020-11-25|2020-11-26|       1|
+----------+----------+--------+
```

I got  the 'group' column by doing these commands:

```py
w1 = Window.orderBy("date")
df_dates.withColumn(
        "dateChange",
        (F.col("datediff") != F.lit(1)).cast("int")
    )\
    .fillna(
        0,
        subset=["dateChange"]
    )\
    .withColumn(
        "indicator",
        (~((F.col("dateChange")==0))).cast("int")
    )\
    .withColumn(
        "group",
        F.sum(F.col("indicator")).over(w1.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
    )
```

and finally got these groupings:

```
+----------+----------+--------+----------+---------+-----+
|      date| next_date|datediff|dateChange|indicator|group|
+----------+----------+--------+----------+---------+-----+
|2020-09-25|2020-09-30|       5|         1|        1|    1|
|2020-09-30|2020-10-01|       1|         0|        0|    1|
|2020-10-01|2020-10-02|       1|         0|        0|    1|
|2020-10-02|2020-10-03|       1|         0|        0|    1|
|2020-10-03|2020-10-04|       1|         0|        0|    1|
|2020-10-09|2020-11-23|      45|         1|        1|    2|
|2020-11-23|2020-11-24|       1|         0|        0|    2|
|2020-11-24|2020-11-25|       1|         0|        0|    2|
|2020-11-25|2020-11-26|       1|         0|        0|    2|
+----------+----------+--------+----------+---------+-----+
```

However, the first row should have its own group. The second row should be group 2 (all incremented by 1).

Then I do the aggregation:

```py
df_dates.groupBy("group")\
    .agg(
        F.min("next_date").alias("start_time"),
        F.max("next_date").alias("end_time")
    )\
    .drop("group")\
    .show()
```

```
+----------+----------+
|start_time|  end_time|
+----------+----------+
|2020-09-30|2020-10-04|
|2020-11-23|2020-11-26|
+----------+----------+
```

But I am missing the first group which is 2020-09-25.

The aim for this is to get the ranges for consecutive dates to help me combine HDFS folders with consecutive dates into the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten example data as python script:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2020-09-25', '2020-09-30',  5),
     ('2020-09-30', '2020-10-01',  1),
     ('2020-10-01', '2020-10-02',  1),
     ('2020-10-02', '2020-10-03',  1),
     ('2020-10-03', '2020-10-04',  1),
     ('2020-10-09', '2020-11-23', 45),
     ('2020-11-23', '2020-11-24',  1),
     ('2020-11-24', '2020-11-25',  1),
     ('2020-11-25', '2020-11-26',  1)],
    ["date", "next_date", "datediff"])
```

The following creates groups using window functions [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) and [`sum`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sum):

```py
w = W.orderBy("date")
# _flg is the rule when subgroup inside partition must be created
df = df.withColumn("_flg", F.coalesce(F.when(F.col("datediff") != F.lag("datediff").over(w), 1), F.lit(0)))
df = df.withColumn("_grp", F.sum("_flg").over(w))

df.show()
# +----------+----------+--------+----+----+
# |      date| next_date|datediff|_flg|_grp|
# +----------+----------+--------+----+----+
# |2020-09-25|2020-09-30|       5|   0|   0|
# |2020-09-30|2020-10-01|       1|   1|   1|
# |2020-10-01|2020-10-02|       1|   0|   1|
# |2020-10-02|2020-10-03|       1|   0|   1|
# |2020-10-03|2020-10-04|       1|   0|   1|
# |2020-10-09|2020-11-23|      45|   1|   2|
# |2020-11-23|2020-11-24|       1|   1|   3|
# |2020-11-24|2020-11-25|       1|   0|   3|
# |2020-11-25|2020-11-26|       1|   0|   3|
# +----------+----------+--------+----+----+
```

Lastly, grouping using the created "_grp" column and others when applicable:

```py
df = (df
    .groupBy("_grp")
    .agg(
        F.min("date").alias("start_time"),
        F.max("next_date").alias("end_time")
    ).drop("_grp")
)
df.show()
# +----------+----------+
# |start_time|  end_time|
# +----------+----------+
# |2020-09-25|2020-09-30|
# |2020-09-30|2020-10-04|
# |2020-10-09|2020-11-23|
# |2020-11-23|2020-11-26|
# +----------+----------+
```